# Group by date using datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a problem while grouping my datatable,

Here is the data,

```
Date                Location
23/07/2014 10:30    Near Highway
23/07/2014 11:30    Near Highway
23/07/2014 12:30    Near Highway
24/07/2014 01:00    From Texas 
24/07/2014 01:10    From Texas 
24/07/2014 01:20    From Texas 
24/07/2014 01:30    From Texas
```

And I want to group by and manipulate the start time, end time and duration based on the location.

```
Date        Start time      End time        Duration        Location
23/07/2014  10:30           12:30           2 hour 00 min   Near Highway
24/07/2014  01:00           01:30           0 hours30 min   From Texas
```

Kindly help me to bring up this solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show me the Query that you had tried

Comment: the problem is , i cant edit the query since it is the default log data. I need to manipulate using c# datatable or linq stuffs...

Comment: Yes group by location but i need to bring the start time and end time from the row data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] 
    {
        new DataColumn("Date",typeof(DateTime)),
        new DataColumn("Location",typeof(string)),
    });
    dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.ParseExact("23/07/2014 10:30", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", new CultureInfo("fr-fr")), "Near Highway");
    dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.ParseExact("23/07/2014 11:30", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", new CultureInfo("fr-fr")), "Near Highway");
    dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.ParseExact("23/07/2014 12:30", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", new CultureInfo("fr-fr")), "Near Highway");
    dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.ParseExact("24/07/2014 01:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", new CultureInfo("fr-fr")), "From Texas");
    dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.ParseExact("24/07/2014 01:10", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", new CultureInfo("fr-fr")), "From Texas");
    dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.ParseExact("24/07/2014 01:20", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", new CultureInfo("fr-fr")), "From Texas");
    dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.ParseExact("24/07/2014 01:30", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", new CultureInfo("fr-fr")), "From Texas");

    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    dt2.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] 
    {
        new DataColumn("Date"),
        new DataColumn("Start time"),
        new DataColumn("End time"),
        new DataColumn("Duration"),
        new DataColumn("Location")
    });
    var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row["Location"]);
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
        var groups2 = group.OrderBy(row => row["Date"]).GroupBy(row => Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        foreach (var group2 in groups2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + group2.Key);
            var list = group2.ToList();
            var startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(list[0]["Date"]);
            var endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(list[list.Count-1]["Date"]);
            TimeSpan ts = endDate-startDate;
            dt2.Rows.Add(group2.Key, startDate.ToString("HH:mm"), endDate.ToString("HH:mm"), ts.Hours + " hour " + ts.Minutes + " minutes", group.Key);
        }
    }
```